# Does spring-retry dependency annotations @Retryable and @Recover create a new thread or are executed in the same thread

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

Does spring retry method creates a new thread when an exception is thrown for the retry and recover annotated method or do they execute in the same thread

Comment: That depends on your configuration.

Comment: Which conofiguration @M.Deinum. Can you give an example or any link that demonstrates this